# CSS display:block and position:fixed

Tags: html, css

Why will this code:

```
div {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
}
```

not display the `div` as `display:block` (i.e. flow across the page) when I add `position:fixed`? It seems to work otherwise?

N.B. I am very new to CSS so I appologise if it is just a silly error

Comment: what do you mean with "flow across the page" and which browser do you use? have you already tried setting left,top,bottom etc?

Comment: div does not have a width or height

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/KFKGk/ see

Comment: @SamithaHewawasam How can I make it flow to the width of the page?

Comment: @Sebiddychef http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/KFKGk/1/

Comment: @Sebiddychef i updated my answer.@guffa already explane the way so i don't need to explane it again

Answer (score 14):

When you use `position: fixed;` or `position: absolute;`, the element is taken out of the regular flow of the document.

The default setting for `width` for a `div` element is `auto`, which means that it will use the full available width where it is. When you take it out of the flow, there is no longer any usable measure for available width (because that would be infinite), so instead the element will get its width from its content.

Comment: How can I make it flow to the width of the page?

Comment: @Sebiddychef: You can't, but you still can use `width: 100%;` to make it have the same width as the parent element. Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Guffa/RLQj6/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add width and height to any [empty] elements with position either `fixed` or `absolute`, otherwise they won't have any size.

```css
html, body {
  height: 1000px;
}

div {
    background-color: yellow;
    display:block;
    position:fixed;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Finally u need something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/tutspack/KFKGk/1/)

Comment: For two navbars, adding a height and top solved for me